# RPC timeout using Control Widget

Tags: thingsboard

As a Thingsboard beginner, I'm having trouble with a simple switch.
I'm trying to integrate a switch widget into the dashboard so that I can query it via API as an attribute or telemetry of a device. The device with a default profile is connected  via a single entity. The RPC defaults are left on the switch in Appearance section. No external hardware.

I've tried various approaches (e.g. return (data=="ON") ? true : false;), read and searched; I constantly get a timeout. Even if I only try to use the RPC remote shell widget: "Unable to get remote platform info. Device is not responding." It seems that the device does not want RPC?
I must be doing or understanding something wrong.

So how can I query a switch widget, or where can I read about it, or get an example?

Comment: Who or what is responsible for processing RPC on a device side?